# SAS check if file on fileserver is opended by other PC

Tags: file, sas

I have a sas-db file on a file server and want to check, if it is opened by another PC.

I tried several attempts using this sources http://www.wuss.org/proceedings11/Papers_Galligan_O_74889.pdf http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0a6vn2td7bjr2n1viy8y4lgvq61.htm with no success. 
The numbers(fid) in the log never turn 0, irrespective if the file is open on the other PC or not.

```
%MACRO Try;

%let filrf=myfile;
%let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,\\inti\[...]\p3001_overviewsampling.sas7bdat));
%let fid=%sysfunc(fopen(&filrf));
%PUT RC is: &RC // fid is &fid ; 

%MEND;
%Try;

LOG: RC is: 20036 // fid is 30
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks, Lubenja

------ EDIT after the answer of data *null* ----------------

Thanks for the repose. However, if I run your macro twice it is not working any more. Somehow the file gets locked even if running from the same PC. And now I cant delete the file any more from whichever PC.

```
17   %LET Path =\\hugo\Temp;
18   LIBNAME test "&Path";
NOTE: Libref TEST was successfully assigned as follows:
      Engine:        V9
      Physical Name: \\hugo\Temp
19
20
21   data test.class2;
22           set sashelp.class;
23   run;

NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
NOTE: The data set TEST.CLASS2 has 19 observations and 5 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.06 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


24
25   %MACRO Try(data=,library=);
26        %let filrf=myfile;
27        %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,%sysfunc(pathname(&library))/&data..sas7bdat));
28        %let fid=%sysfunc(fopen(&filrf,O));
29        %PUT RC is: &RC // fid is &fid ;
30        %if &fid %then %let rc=%sysfunc(fclose(&fid));
31   %MEND;
32   %Try(data=class2,library=test);
RC is: 0 // fid is 1

33   %Try(data=class2,library=test);
RC is: 0 // fid is 0

34   data test.class2;
35           set sashelp.class;
36   run;

ERROR: An I/O error has occurred on file TEST.CLASS2.DATA.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Comment: If you are wanting to lock a SAS dataset in order to write to it take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17871132/214994 .

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the O output option to FOPEN

```
25         data class;
26            set sashelp.class;
27            run;

NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
NOTE: The data set WORK.CLASS has 19 observations and 5 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.02 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


28         %let did = %sysfunc(open(class));
29         %put &=did;
DID=1
30         
31         %MACRO Try(data=);
32            %let filrf=myfile;
33            %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,%sysfunc(pathname(work))/&data..sas7bdat));
34            %let fid=%sysfunc(fopen(&filrf,O));
35            %PUT RC is: &RC // fid is &fid ;
36            %if &fid %then %let rc=%sysfunc(fclose(&fid));
37            %MEND;
38         %Try(data=class)
Resource is read-locked by another thread.  File 
=/opt/local/saswork/...redacted.../class.sas7bdat.
RC is: 0 // fid is 0
39         
40         %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&did));
41         %put &=rc;
RC=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the repose. However, if I run your macro twice it is not working any more. Somehow the file gets locked. 
Please see the detail above in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an approach to handling this case, although unfortunately it still writes an ERROR to the log:

```
%let lib=YOURLIB;
%let ds=YOURDS;

/* first - test for syscc>0 and handle */
/* next, attempt to gain update access and set var if successful */
%let locked=yes;
data &lib..&ds;
  modify &lib..&ds;
  call symputx('locked','no');
  stop;
run;

/* if error, or explicity locked, handle the case */
%if &syscc>0 or &locked=yes %then %do;
  %let syscc=0;
  options obs=max replace nosyntaxcheck;
  /* DO SOMETHING HERE */
%end;
```