# Table lock not available...Any way to hold(wait) program until data set(table) release?

Tags: sql, sas, locking

Is that possible to hold(wait) a program which run through scheduler until particular table or data set get released? Because of some table lock my scheduler program is failing. I cannot change my SAS console run time. I just wanted to know is there any code that hold running program until some particular table release and program keep on refresh until unless table is unlocked

I have tried using below code but failed to continue.

```
PROC SQL;
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE.VIKAS_DETAILS (EMPID,AGE, SEX, STATE, COUNTRY) 
            SELECT DISTINCT EMPID, AGE, SEX, STATE, COUNTRY FROM WORK.FINAL_EMPLOYEE; 
QUIT;
```

ERROR:

> A lock is not available for EMPLOYEE.VIKAS.DATA.

I am getting this error because one of my other program also inserting same variable to above data sets but with different data's.

Comment: checkout this paper. https://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2005/posters/po33.pdf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862400/how-do-i-stop-a-lock-is-not-available-for-dataset-errors-in-sas

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on the version of SAS and the libname statement that defines the `EMPLOYEE` libref.  However, you can try adding `FILELOCKWAIT=` option to the libname

```
libname EMPLOYEE … FILELOCKWAIT=300; /* wait up to 5 minutes when a member is locked from use */
```

> **FILELOCKWAIT=n**
>   specifies the number of seconds SAS waits for a locked
>   file to become available to another process. If the locked file is
>   released before the number of seconds specified by n, then SAS locks
>   the file for the current process and continues. If the file is still
>   locked when the number of seconds has been reached, then SAS writes a
>   "Locked File" error to the log and the DATA step fails.